# TFS backlog showing items from the wrong team/area

Tags: tfs

We have a project defined in TFS (TFS 2012 - using scrum process template) that has three teams and three areas defined. In the latest sprint, the backlog and sprint board for one of the teams (Red team) is showing items that are assigned to that team, as well as one of the other teams (Blue team).

When a member of Red team views their backlog items for the current sprint, they see items that are assigned to both Red and Blue teams. When a Red team member opens the Board page, and clicks the "Person" link in the top right of the page to filter the board for a given person, the list of persons displayed includes all members from both Red and Blue teams.

When members of the Blue or Green teams view their boards and backlogs, they only see the items assigned to their own team, as expected.

I can't find any problems in the way the teams and areas are defined, and we've been running with these three teams with no problem for two years. It is just the current sprint that is showing this problem.

Any ideas of what could have caused this problem?

Comment: What's the team's backlog iteration set to?

Comment: Both teams have their backlog iteration set to the same path.

Comment: Another interesting problem I just found. If I look at the past iterations, I see the same problem. Looking at the backlog for a past iteration for Red team shows items from both Red and Blue teams, while the iterations for the Blue team displays just the completed Blue team items. So whatever caused the backlog items to display for both teams also affected the way past backlogs are displayed.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found the problem. There are three areas defined in the team project - one for each team. I check the admin page for each team for the area definitions; in the case of the Red team, that page showed that the Red team owned the areas for both Red and Blue teams. Clearing the checkbox for the area specific for the Blue team corrected the problem.